# How to use a value from a specific field for security rules for firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My database schema is shown below:

> 

```
 {
   "Shifts":{
      "ShiftID":{
         "name":"name",
         "place":"place",
         "ID":"ID"
      }
   },
   {
      "ShiftID":{
         "name":"name",
         "place":"place",
         "ID":"ID"
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to establish firebase database rules such that theh rule compares the ID of each strings and grants access to read or write only if it matches a specific ID. Following is what I have for my rule so far but it seems to be giving access denied error.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Shifts": {
         "$shift": {
           ".write": "true",
                ".read": "data.child('ID').val()=== 'specificID'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2cyB.png)

Comment: Show us a concrete example from your database. A single child would be enough.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have added a screenshot above please have a look at your convenience.

Comment: WHat exactly is `specificID`?

Comment: So in my example it’s UID. For each user. Each shift record will have a UID associated with it and I am looking to see if it matches the UID of the logged in user

Comment: "one" doesn't seem to be an UID, right?